# Issue while using react-picky select menu

Tags: reactjs

I have recently downloaded the react-picky and have used it inside a map function to loop through my dynamic data. In the picky i have set multiselect as true.
How ever on the onchange function am getting only the currently selected value and not the list of values selected for picky.

The issue am facing is in the case of multiselect where the value will be a single object containing the current selected item rather than the list of items selected. Could you please help me with the issue. I have tried every possible solution and it does not seem to work.Any help would be really appreciated as am stuck in the issue for sometime.

```
const sectorsData = [
  {
    name: "Technology",
    options: [
      {
        id: "1",
        name: "AI & Analytics"
      },
      {
        id: "2",
        name: "Robotics"
      },
      {
        id: "3",
        name: "IoT"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Sector",
    options: [
      {
        id: "1",
        name: "Automotive"
      },
      {
        id: "2",
        name: "Oil and gas"
      },
      {
        id: "3",
        name: "Consumer Products"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Accounts",
    options: [
      {
        id: "1",
        name: "Alphabet Inc."
      },
      {
        id: "2",
        name: "General Motors Company"
      },
      {
        id: "3",
        name: "Consumer Products"
      },
      {
        id: "4",
        name: "State Street Corporation"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Region",
    options: [
      {
        id: "1",
        name: "Canada Region"
      },
      {
        id: "2",
        name: "Central"
      },
      {
        id: "3",
        name: "FSO Americas"
      },
      {
        id: "4",
        name: "Latam North"
      },
      {
        id: "5",
        name: "Latam South"
      }
    ]
  }
];

const App = props => {
  const [assetsAddedState, setAssetsAddedState] = React.useState({
    selectedItems: []
  });

  const selectedOption = (name, value) => {
    setAssetsAddedState(prev => {
      return { ...prev, [name]: value };
    });
  };

  return (
    <form className="create-work-form-container" noValidate autoComplete="off">
      {sectorsData.map((selectItem, i) => (
        <Picky
          value={assetsAddedState[selectItem.name]}
          onChange={selectedOption.bind(this, selectItem.name)}
          options={selectItem.options}
          placeholder={selectItem.name}
          numberDisplayed={1}
          valueKey="id"
          labelKey="name"
          multiple={true}
          includeSelectAll={true}
          includeFilter={true}
          dropdownHeight={600}
          className="multiSelectControl "
          name={selectItem.name}
        />
      ))}
    </form>
  );
};
```

value should be returning the multiple values user has selected.

Comment: If you can, please provide a SandBox with an example with minimal functionality.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/picky-demo-l8gpj  , could you please try this

Answer (score 0):

See if this is working for you:

Working example on CodeSandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-pickyanswerso-yp02j

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Picky from "react-picky";
import "react-picky/dist/picky.css";

const sector1 = {
  name: "Technology",
  options: [
    {
      id: "1",
      name: "AI & Analytics"
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      name: "Robotics"
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      name: "IoT"
    }
  ]
};
const sector2 = {
  name: "Sector",
  options: [
    {
      id: "4",
      name: "Automotive"
    },
    {
      id: "5",
      name: "Oil and gas"
    },
    {
      id: "6",
      name: "Consumer Products"
    }
  ]
};
const sector3 = {
  name: "Accounts",
  options: [
    {
      id: "7",
      name: "Alphabet Inc."
    },
    {
      id: "8",
      name: "General Motors Company"
    },
    {
      id: "9",
      name: "Consumer Products"
    },
    {
      id: "10",
      name: "State Street Corporation"
    }
  ]
};

const sector4 = {
  name: "Region",
  options: [
    {
      id: "11",
      name: "Canada Region"
    },
    {
      id: "12",
      name: "Central"
    },
    {
      id: "13",
      name: "FSO Americas"
    },
    {
      id: "14",
      name: "Latam North"
    },
    {
      id: "15",
      name: "Latam South"
    }
  ]
};

const App = props => {
  // const [assetsAddedState, setAssetsAddedState] = React.useState([]);

  const [selected1, setSelected1] = React.useState([]);
  const [selected2, setSelected2] = React.useState([]);
  const [selected3, setSelected3] = React.useState([]);
  const [selected4, setSelected4] = React.useState([]);

  const selectedOption1 = value => {
    console.log("VAlue: " + JSON.stringify(value));
    setSelected1(value);
  };

  const selectedOption2 = value => {
    console.log("VAlue: " + JSON.stringify(value));
    setSelected2(value);
  };

  const selectedOption3 = value => {
    console.log("VAlue: " + JSON.stringify(value));
    setSelected3(value);
  };

  const selectedOption4 = value => {
    console.log("VAlue: " + JSON.stringify(value));
    setSelected4(value);
  };

  return (
    <form className="create-work-form-container" noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <Picky
        value={selected1}
        onChange={selectedOption1}
        options={sector1.options}
        placeholder={sector1.name}
        numberDisplayed={1}
        valueKey="id"
        labelKey="name"
        multiple={true}
        includeSelectAll={true}
        includeFilter={true}
        dropdownHeight={600}
        className="multiSelectControl "
        name={sector1.name}
      />
      <Picky
        value={selected2}
        onChange={selectedOption2}
        options={sector2.options}
        placeholder={sector2.name}
        numberDisplayed={1}
        valueKey="id"
        labelKey="name"
        multiple={true}
        includeSelectAll={true}
        includeFilter={true}
        dropdownHeight={600}
        className="multiSelectControl "
        name={sector2.name}
      />
      <Picky
        value={selected3}
        onChange={selectedOption3}
        options={sector3.options}
        placeholder={sector3.name}
        numberDisplayed={1}
        valueKey="id"
        labelKey="name"
        multiple={true}
        includeSelectAll={true}
        includeFilter={true}
        dropdownHeight={600}
        className="multiSelectControl "
        name={sector3.name}
      />
      <Picky
        value={selected4}
        onChange={selectedOption4}
        options={sector4.options}
        placeholder={sector4.name}
        numberDisplayed={1}
        valueKey="id"
        labelKey="name"
        multiple={true}
        includeSelectAll={true}
        includeFilter={true}
        dropdownHeight={600}
        className="multiSelectControl "
        name={sector4.name}
      />
    </form>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Hi, it works fine when I have different picky components, however when  I try to make it dynamic inside a map function with multiselect true it fails.